# In a list of anchor tags, how can i access a specific tag's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple series of anchor tags and I want the text of the anchor to appear in an input field.

How can I use Javascript to identify the clicked anchor rather than the first anchor tag, as in the attached script?
    
      
        Sum

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test()
    {
        var var1 = document.getElementById('add2').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('add').value = var1;
    }
    </script>

  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <FORM NAME="myform">

      <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="add" NAME="result" VALUE=""/>
    </FORM>

  </BODY>
  <br>
  <br>

        <a id="add2" onclick="test()" href="#" >Test1</a>
        <br>
         <a id="add2" onclick="test()" href="#" >Test2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jquery. Just add class to the anchor tags.

```
<body>
    <FORM NAME="myform">
      <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="add" NAME="result" VALUE=""/>
    </FORM>
  <br>
  <br>

        <a id="add1" class="anchor" href="javascript:void(0)" >Test1</a>
        <br>
         <a id="add2" class="anchor" href="javascript:void(0)" >Test2</a>
</body>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".anchor").click(function() {
        var val = $(this).text();
        $("#add").val(val);
    });
});
```

You can see it working here. https://jsfiddle.net/ctzzfqm1/

Answer (score 0):

You should pass clicked element object to method:

```
 <a id="add2" onclick="test(this)" href="#" >Test1</a>
 <a id="add2" onclick="test(this)" href="#" >Test2</a>
```

and then use the element context to access its text:

```
function test(obj){
   document.getElementById('add').value =  obj.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for all of your responses. I've learnt a great deal and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qdbsto3t/)

```
$('.a').click(function () {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

You can add a class on the anchor tag then on click get the text

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working as IDs in HTML must be unique. I would recommend to bind event using `addEventListener` instead of ugly inline click handlers

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('add2');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('add').value = this.innerHTML;
    }, false);
  }
}
```

```html
<INPUT TYPE="text" ID="add" NAME="result" VALUE="" />
<br>
<a class='add2' href="#">Test1</a>
<br>
<a class='add2' href="#">Test2</a>
```

References:

1. [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
2. [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)